# DRF: Right way to use ListCreateAPIView with nested serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I make a page that lists all the existing vendors and modules that apply to each vendor. Here I need to change the status of modules (active or unactive), and if the module does not exist, but  need to make it active then create it. It looks roughly like this.

```
Vendor1   module1/false  module2/true   module3/true .....
Vendor2   module1/false  module2/true   module3/true .....
.....
.....
```

**models.py**

```
class RfiParticipation(models.Model):
    vendor = models.ForeignKey('Vendors', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='to_vendor')
    m = models.ForeignKey('Modules', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='to_modules')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    rfi = models.ForeignKey('Rfis', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='to_rfi', blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

To display it, I use  ListCreateAPIView() class and nested serializer

**serializer.py**

```
class VendorModulesListManagementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    to_vendor = RfiParticipationSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Vendors
        fields = ('vendorid', 'vendor_name', 'to_vendor',)
        read_only_fields = ('vendorid', 'vendor_name', )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data = validated_data.pop('to_vendor')
        for validated_data in validated_data:
            module, created = RfiParticipation.objects.update_or_create(
                rfi=validated_data.get('rfi', None),
                vendor=validated_data.get('vendor', None),
                m=validated_data.get('m', None),
                defaults={'active': validated_data.get('active', False)})
        return module


class RfiParticipationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = RfiParticipation
        fields = ('pk', 'active', 'm', 'rfi', 'vendor', 'timestamp')
        read_only_fields = ('timestamp', )
```

**views.py**

```
class AssociateModulesWithVendorView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    RFI: List of vendors with participated modules and modules status
    """
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny, ]
    serializer_class = VendorModulesListManagementSerializer
    queryset = Vendors.objects.all()
```

I have a question about using the create serializer method when sending a POST request.

Now the input format looks like this

```
{
    "to_vendor": [
            {
                "active": false,
                "m": 1,
                "rfi": "20R1",
                "vendor": 15

            }]
}
```

I.e. the dictionary key for the current code implementation is the list of one dictionary. If I remove " [] " from dict value I got

```
{
    "to_vendor": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"."
        ]
    }
}
```

And this is the reason why I need to add a for loop  in the create method to iterate through the list with just one element. I already have any doubts that I'm doing the right thing. Maybe I chose the wrong implementation way?

But now question is why do I get a mistake?

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `to_vendor` on serializer `VendorModulesListManagementSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `RfiParticipation` instance.
Original exception text was: 'RfiParticipation' object has no attribute 'to_vendor'.
```

I would be very grateful for your help and advice!

**upd**

Get request format data:

```
[
    {
        "vendorid": 15,
        "vendor_name": "Forest Gamp",
        "to_vendor": [
            {
                "pk": 35,
                "active": true,
                "m": "Sourcing",
                "rfi": "1",
                "vendor": 15,
                "timestamp": "2020-03-29T08:15:41.638427"
            },
            {
                "pk": 39,
                "active": false,
                "m": "CLM",
                "rfi": "20R1",
                "vendor": 15,
                "timestamp": "2020-03-29T09:09:03.431111"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "vendorid": 16,
        "vendor_name": "Test21fd2",
        "to_vendor": [
            {
                "pk": 41,
                "active": false,
                "m": "SA",
                "rfi": "20R1",
                "vendor": 16,
                "timestamp": "2020-03-30T11:05:16.106412"
            },
            {
                "pk": 40,
                "active": false,
                "m": "CLM",
                "rfi": "20R1",
                "vendor": 16,
                "timestamp": "2020-03-30T10:40:52.799763"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It tries to access `to_vendor` on your model `RfiParticipation` and it complains that this property does not exist. `related_name` refers to the back relation on your `Vendors` model. So that you can do something like `Vendors.to_vendor.all()` and fetch all the `RfiParticipation` instances.

This happens when it tries to validate your input data, so even before it gets to the create function of your serializer.

If you are trying to create new `RfiParticipation`, why would you use a view that defines `queryset = Vendors.objects.all()`?

Instead define a view that takes care of creating `RfiParticipation`, since it seems that you already have a reference to `Vendors`. If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do is basically batch create `RfiParticipation`, so make a view that points to these.

Comment: The strange thing is when I make a `GET` request, the connection to_vendor works. And as soon as I send a `POST`, an error occurs. 
I use Vendor because I need a certain nested structure that I added to the question update.   
If I use the `RfiParticipation` object, I can't get it, or I just don't know how to do it. Bulc_upload is not exactly what I need. Updating or creating a module happens every time you click on a checkbox. That is, there is no setting of many checkboxes and then sending all of them with one request. One checkbox is one request to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your implementation, and I suppose you might have used wrong ***generics class inheritance*** in views.py.

You should try to replace

```
class AssociateModulesWithVendorView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny, ]
    serializer_class = VendorModulesListManagementSerializer
    queryset = Vendors.objects.all()
```

With

```
class AssociateModulesWithVendorView(generics.CreateAPIView, generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny, ]
    serializer_class = VendorModulesListManagementSerializer
    queryset = Vendors.objects.all()
```

You can check below links for reference:
CreateAPIView : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createmodelmixin
ListCreateAPIView : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview

Comment: I think using your version is no different than mine. It's the same functionality. I solved my problem using different serializer for POST and GET method.